# C# UWP The property was not found in viewmodel

Tags: c#, viewmodel, uwp-xaml

My CollectionViewSource gets a underline in VS with the following message: "Property 'Courses' was not found in MainPageViewModel" and I can't seem to find out why it won't be found, so I'm looking for help. My MainPage.xaml looks like this:

```
<Page x:Class="CourseStudent.UWP.Views.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
      xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
      xmlns:controls="using:Template10.Controls"
      xmlns:converters="using:Template10.Converters"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="using:CourseStudent.UWP.Views"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:vm="using:CourseStudent.UWP.ViewModels" mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Page.Resources>
        <converters:StringFormatConverter x:Key="CoursesHeaderConverter" Format="Courses ({0})"/>

        <!-- Collection of courses displayed by this page -->
        <CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="coursesViewSource"
            Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.Courses}"
            d:Source="{d:DesignData /SampleData/CoursesSampleData.xaml}"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <controls:PageHeader x:Name="pageHeader" Content="Main Page"
                             RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                             RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                             RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" />

        <TextBlock x:Name="mainTextBlock" Margin="16,12,0,0"
                   RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.Below="pageHeader" Text="Courses" />

    </RelativePanel>

</Page>
```

And my MainPageViewModel.cs looks like this

```
using CourseStudent.Model;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Template10.Mvvm;
using Template10.Services.NavigationService;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace CourseStudent.UWP.ViewModel
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            if (Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
            { }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Course> courses;
        public ObservableCollection<Course> Courses { get { return courses; } set { Set(ref courses, value); } }

        public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> suspensionState)
        {
            if (Courses == null) // get courses from the data API
            {
                Courses = new ObservableCollection<Course>
                {
                    new Course() { CourseName = "blabla"},
                    new Course() { CourseName = "bloblo"},
                    new Course() { CourseName = "jojo"},

                };
            }

            if (suspensionState.Any())
            {
            }
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public override async Task OnNavigatedFromAsync(IDictionary<string, object> suspensionState, bool suspending)
        {
            if (suspending)
            {
            }
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public override async Task OnNavigatingFromAsync(NavigatingEventArgs args)
        {
            args.Cancel = false;
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there's anyone here who can see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your binding to be

```
Source="{x:Bind Courses}"
```

(remove the `ViewModel.` part)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, error only changed to say Cannot find property in MainPage instead of MainPageViewModel though

Comment: Can you try, `Source={x:Bind Path=Courses, ElementName=ViewModel}"

Comment: Thanks, still no go, Path=Courses still gives me the property in MainPage error and ElementName=ViewModel gives me the "property 'ElementName' was not found in bind

Comment: Try {Binding} instead of {x:Bind}

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the namespace for the `MainPageViewModel` is `CourseStudent.UWP.ViewModel` on your side, but what you reference is `using:CourseStudent.UWP.ViewModels` which has additional `s` added. You could try to check this firstly.

Beside this, I cannot reproduce your issue on my side. Since your code snippet is not the completed, so I provide a minimal worked demo you could reference.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
<Page.Resources>
    <!--  Collection of courses displayed by this page  -->
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="coursesViewSource" Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.Courses}" />
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource coursesViewSource}}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Course">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CourseName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

MainPageViewModel

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        courses = new ObservableCollection<Course>()
        {
            new Course() { CourseName = "blabla"},
            new Course() { CourseName = "bloblo"},
            new Course() { CourseName = "jojo"}
        };
    }
    ObservableCollection<Course> courses;
    public ObservableCollection<Course> Courses { get => courses; set => courses = value; } 
}

public class Course
{
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
}
```

Try to add more code on a working small demo to narrow the issue. If you still have issues, please provide the minimal reproduced project.